# can't fire click eventListener on font awesome icons in javascript

Tags: javascript, font-awesome, addeventlistener

I have been trying to make a simple todo list in which i have added font awesome icons in front of every list item , but when i click on that icon it doesn't gets removed from the list....
Here's my js code:

```
   const list = document.querySelector('.list');

   list.addEventListener('click', e => {
    if (e.target.className === fa-solid') {
        let li = e.target.parentNode;
        li.parentNode.removeChild(li);
    }
})
```

here `fa-solid` is the class of the font awesome icon and when i click on this icon my code doesn't run.

Comment: The code as currently shown contains syntax errors. And the class of your icons is probably not _just_ `fa-solid`. Please always show a proper [mre] with questions like this.

Answer (score 1):

I got the solution for my question.
The only thing that was wrong in my code was the name of the class of font awesome icon. We have to pass the entire class name in the code and not just `fa-solid`.

```
const list = document.querySelector('.list');

list.addEventListener('click', e => {
    if (e.target.className === 'fa-solid fa-trash-can') {
        let li = e.target.parentNode;
        li.parentNode.removeChild(li);
    }
})
```

That's it.

Comment: you could use `e.target.classList.contains('fa-trash-can')` - since `fa-trash-can` is probably the key here and `fa-solid` is a modifier of sorts. While the order of classes in a fontawesome icon may be predictable, you can't guarantee it - best to target the main icon name

Answer (score -1):

you messing ' in the if statement  'fa-solid'

```js
const list = document.querySelector('.list');

   list.addEventListener('click', e => {
    if (e.target.className === 'fa-solid') {
        let li = e.target.parentNode;
        li.parentNode.removeChild(li);
    }
})
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

There is a quote missing in front of fa-solid inside the if

```
if (e.target.className === 'fa-solid')
```